# How to save frame from VOB with correct size?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am saving single frames from a vob file with ffmpeg.

ffprobe shows for my vob file:

> Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x480
>   [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], Closed Captions, 3750 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr,
>   90k tbn, 59.94 tbc

My command line is

> ffmpeg -i File1.vob -ss 10 -q:v 2 -vframes 1 -an -sn frame10s.jpg

My jpeg files are being saved with 720x480, horizontally stretched. How can I make them be saved with correct display ratio 640x480?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i File1.vob -ss 10 -vf scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1 -q:v 2 -vframes 1 frame10s.jpg
```

The scaler multiples the input width by the stored pixel aspect ratio to produce a square pixel representation.

Image formats don't support audio or subtitles so disabling those isn't necessary.

Comment: Why is setting sar=1 also necessary?

Comment: Just to make sure the resulting SAR is exactly 1. Occasionally it can be recorded as something like 2800:2801, especially in PNGs.